# Android widget truncated

Tags: android, android-widget

I'm facing a newbie problem designing a widget.
My widget should have 4 ImageViews and a TextView as header.
When I put 3 ImageViews this is the correct result: [image: Widget with 3 images]

After adding the fourth image my widget gets truncated:[image: Widget with 4 images]

As you can see last image (that is 64x64 like others) is shrinked.
Why?
I've just red [this link](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/widget_design.html#sizes), but even if I try to set fixed width to 320dip, my widget is not correct.

Here is widget layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dip" android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:background="#4E7FAB" android:textColor="#FFA10E"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/status_layout" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray">

        <ImageView android:id="@+id/widget_usage" android:src="@drawable/usage_none"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true" />
        <ImageView android:src="@drawable/div" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/widget_behaviour" android:src="@drawable/beh_drop"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true" />
        <ImageView android:src="@drawable/div" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView android:id="@+id/widget_calls" android:background="@drawable/missed_calls_zero"
            android:layout_width="64dip" android:layout_height="64dip"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:textStyle="bold" android:text="0" />
        <ImageView android:src="@drawable/div" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/widget_contacts" android:src="@drawable/contacts"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Try setting `android:layout_width="64dip"` for the 3 `ImageView` elements and see if that fixes it.

Comment: What is the contents of AppWidgetProviderInfo, especially the value minWidth?

Comment: @MisterSquonk: yes, that worked!! Anyway I tried to change my AppWidgetProviderInfo xml and finally I was able to make it works: setting `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` for every ImageView and `android:minWidth="262dip"` for ProviderInfo, job is done. Anyway I don't understand the reason of this behaviour, really. If you post your comment as answer I will accept this. Thanks for helping me!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turning my comment / suggestion to answer as you asked.

Try setting android:layout_width="64dip" for the 3 ImageView elements and see if that fixes it.

I'm not 100% sure why it fixed it but I suspect it has something to do with the screen size of your emulator and the actual size of the images (in real pixels) compared to the `dip`.

For further information, this from the Dev Guide...[Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) and in particular the section describing how different sizes and densities work...[Range of screens supported](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#range)

Glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
android:layout_width="64dip"
```

or

```
android:layout_width="0dip" android:layout_weight="1"
```

on every ImageView

Answer (score 0):

And I can't answer your AppWidgetProviderInfo, so I'll post it here:

Here you find all
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetProviderInfo.html